# Vue Js. router/Index.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, router

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcDdX.png)

Hi everyone,

The screenshot shows a menu from a website built with vue js. What I want to do is to redirect to external resources such as google.com outside the site when this menu is clicked. Is it possible to do this in router/index.js?

```
let router = new Router({
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
mode: "history",
routes: [
    {
        path: "/xxx",
        name: "dashboard",
        meta: {},
        url: "www.xxxxafafa.org" // as this
    },
```

With the path field, it is understood which menu is the clicked menu. Since the code will enter here when this menu is clicked on the page, what I want to do is to redirect to any external source from within the block.

I will be waiting for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Per-Route Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard)

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.xxxxafafa.org'
}
```